# Having multiple forms is the same page and submit one of them

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a main View that contains multiple forms. These forms are in different PartialViews but one on them which is in the main view.

The problem is that after the form in the main view is submitted, I noticed other [HttpPost] actions related to the forms in PartialViews are submitted too!

I know using Ajax techniques for submitting forms addresses the problem but I’m looking for other solutions.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe I can mistake , but it shouldn't happen , can you shate you view code ?

Comment: is forms nested inside main form?

Comment: There could be any number of issues that would cause this behavior. For instance, are you using jQuery and binding the submit event to all the forms? We would need to see the code for the view to help you out.

Comment: Well, I wrote a simple example and uploaded on http://www.mediafire.com/?iwas44k2x2izrkn  
when you click on the form1 button, [HttpPost]Index action is executed and then [HttpPost]Form2 action will be executed too!  I don't know why [HttpPost]Form2 action should be executed.